# Fullcalendar - Looking for alternative way to hide events

Tags: javascript, arrays, fullcalendar

Sorry I am new at this, so please excuse the potential lack of info, just ask for anything and I'll try to provide it.

I'm using full calendar v5

I've added the validRange code to hide my past events, but this also hides everything else as well including the days of the month in the dayGridMonth view, so I now only have half a calendar month displayed.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var initialLocaleCode = 'en-gb';
  var localeSelectorEl = document.getElementById('locale-selector');
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      validRange: function(nowDate) {
        return {
          start: nowDate,
          // end: nowDate.clone().add(1, 'months')
        };
      },
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,today,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,listYear'
      },
      views: {
        // titleFormat: { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: '2-digit' },
        dayGridMonth: {
          titleFormat: {
            month: 'short',
          },
          buttonText: 'Month'
        }, //year: 'numeric'
        listYear: {
          buttonText: 'Year'
        },
      },
      locale: initialLocaleCode,
      displayEventTime: false,
      navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      editable: false,
      dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      height: 'auto',
      events: [
        id: '1',
        title: 'Raft Race',
        start: '2020-07-03T00:00:00',
        end: '2020-07-05T24:00:00',
        color: 'red',
        textColor: 'black',
        url: 'details/20.html'
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        title: 'Charity Rally',
        start: '2020-07-10T00:00:00',
        end: '2020-07-12T24:00:00',
        color: 'yellow',
        textColor: 'black',
        url: 'details/21.html'
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        title: 'Bedford River Festival',
        start: '2020-07-17T00:00:00',
        end: '2020-07-19T24:00:00',
        color: 'red',
        textColor: 'black',
        url: 'details/22a.html'
      },
      {
        id: '4',
        title: 'Event - Norfolk Motorhome Show',
        start: '2020-07-24T00:00:00',
        end: '2020-07-26T24:00:00',
        color: 'red',
        textColor: 'black',
        url: 'details/22b.html'
      },
      {
        id: '5',
        title: 'Everglades Caravan Park',
        start: '2020-07-18T00:00:00',
        end: '2020-07-26T24:00:00',
        color: 'red',
        textColor: 'black',
        url: 'details/23.html'
      },
      {
        id: '6',
        title: '70th Anniversary Rally',
        start: '2020-07-23T00:00:00',
        end: '2020-07-26T24:00:00',
        color: 'red',
        textColor: 'black',
        url: 'details/24a.html'
      },
      {
        id: '7',
        title: 'The Birches',
        start: '2020-07-24T00:00:00',
        end: '2020-07-26T24:00:00',
        color: 'lime',
        textColor: 'black',
        url: 'details/24b.html'
      },
      {
        id: '8',
        title: 'Dunstable Rugby Club',
        start: '2020-07-31T00:00:00',
        end: '2020-08-02T24:00:00',
        color: 'red',
        textColor: 'black',
        url: 'details/25.html'
      }
    ]
  }); calendar.render();
});
```

I am looking for a script that will hide the events similar to by adding the display option from "block" to "none" in the event array on the day after the event has finished.  That way all calendar dates are then still displayed but not the event.

Snippet of event array with the display option included below which hides an event, but I don't want to put this into the arrray:

```
{
  id: '6',
  title: '70th Anniversary Rally',
  start: '2020-07-23T00:00:00',
  end: '2020-07-26T24:00:00',
  color: 'red',
  textColor: 'black',
  url: 'details/24a.html'
  display: 'none'
}
,
```

I hope this is possible and look forward to suggestions

Comment: You might have to tell what is this fullCalender? Link to this package perhaps will help see what does it say in its documentation.

Comment: @Praym look at the fullCalendar tag (click the blue tag to go to its page and then click "learn more"). This is one reason we use tags in SO, so you can understand what technologies the question is referring to. Alternative, you could just google it, it's not hard to find.

Comment: Andy, if you don't want to display past events, then why not just exclude them from your event feed in the first place? Am I missing something?